# PHP - Edit XML file that contains a string

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I wanna change a line in a XML file that contains a code obtained via POST.

I am searching for a way to find the file on XML files' directory that contains the code, for then change the line.

Can someone help me?

My PHP code:

```
$files = scandir('xml/.'); // List files
foreach($files as $file) { 
  if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue; 
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/".$file);
  $result = $xml->xpath("pedido"); 
  if($result[3]->numpedido == $dilma) {
   echo "It exists!";
  }
}

/* My XML Looks like this
<pedido>
  <cliente>João</cliente>
  <mesa>34</mesa>
  <hora>13:01:10</hora>
  <numpedido>6780110</numpedido>
  <lista>Baiao, Frango, Porco, e Macaxeira</lista>
  <status>Aberto</status>
</pedido>
*/
```

Edit: The error that I am getting is:

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/restaurante/cmae/rita.php on line 43

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/restaurante/cmae/rita.php on line 43

Comment: What do you think that `$result[3]` is?

Comment: I wonder that ```$result[3]``` could be the 4th row of the array ```$result[]```, that contains the childs of ```<pedido>```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$result = $xml->xpath("pedido");` will not return any result. You need
to change your xpath to `$result = $xml->xpath("/pedido");`. That way you will have an array with simple XML elements (the handling of result needs to be different).

```
if (isset($result[0]) && isset($result[0]->numpedido) && $result[0]->numpedido == $dilma) {
    echo 'exists';
}
```

Comment: You can help me how to handle the results? I tried to use a ```foreach ($xml->children() as $child){ . . . }```  but it doesn't worked, then I tried to use ```$result[5]->status = $temer;``` ($temer is also received from POST) but it also doesn't worked. :/ [Edit: I need to change the <status> line on XML]

Comment: If you will use the example which I provide and do slight change `echo 'exists'; to $result[0]->status = 'statusToChange';` then you have changed xml in the object $xml (because of references). Next steps is save the file file_put_contents("xml/".$file, $xml->asXML());

Comment: `$result = $xml->xpath("/pedido");` will assign an array that contains the same node as the `$xml` variable (or nothing). Basically `$result[0]->numpedido` and `$xml->numpedido` are the same. The Xpath is not needed. It will be different if `pedido` is not the root node.